# How do I get a Hero Forge model using a wheelchair?

Tags: miniatures, hero-forge

I would like to create a character using a wheelchair in [Hero Forge](https://www.heroforge.com) (unaffiliated with me), but I can't find the options under legs, race or gear?

Where is the option?

Comment: @Theik [What is spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/175002)

Comment: Making a complete trivial question that could be answered without linking to an advertisement riddled website that earns money from clicks, only to link to it sounds like the very definition of both promoting a product (website) AND being unsolicited, because the article adds absolutely nothing that couldn't already be answered by the rest of the answer.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Do you now or have you ever had any business association with HeroForge or Dice Breaker?

Comment: @theik, I'm showing my sources. I didn't know, I googled (Stackexchange didn't come up), and I used the content of the article to help answer. I didn't see *any* adverts on that page when I read it earlier, and I still don't now. I could change it to the Twitter page they link to, but that only has a video and no explanation of how to find the option. Also twitter runs ads as well so ... ‍♂️

Comment: @ThomasMarkov no affiliation or business association, I don't even have a subscription to either website.

Comment: Then according to the laws of Stack Exchange, this is not a post that should be flagged for spam: “A post should be marked as spam only if it promotes a product, service, or similar; and is unsolicited or lacks disclosure of affiliation.” You are answering a genuine, on topic question, and have no affiliation with either HeroForge or Dice Breaker. This is indisputably not spam, and anyone who is filed a spam flag needs to retract it, please. If you don’t like the question, the tool here is downvoting, not red flagging.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This dicebreaker [article](https://www.dicebreaker.com/companies/hero-forge/news/hero-forge-wheelchair-user-miniatures) (unaffiliated with me) helped me find where the options are located.

> Now your heroes can now choose from three Wheelchair styles in the Mount menu: The Modern Wheelchair, Fantasy Town Wheelchair, and Fantasy Battle Wheelchair.

They're currently under 'Stage > Ride':

[image: HeroForge model before applying the wheelchair option]

And here is how the character looks afterwards:

[image: HeroForge model after applying the wheelchair option]

This 'ride' works on all leg types, except centaur. Yes, even 'serpent' and 'merfolk' legs